# I replaced the motor in my dryer and it died almost immediately - can I just get another motor or is there likely another problem?

Tags: dryer, appliances, electric-motor

Dryer is a Samsung DV42H5000EW/AC that is about 4 years old.

I did the diagnostics with my multimeter as described in the little  booklet on the back of the dryer, found it was the motor, and replaced it. Everything worked normally for about 24 hours but then the same problem started up again.

I did the diagnostic steps from the booklet on the dryer on the new motor which specify:

- 2.88 ohms between pins 3 and 4 - I got 1.8 ohms
- 3.5 ohms between pins 4 and 5 - I got 1.9 ohms

So this seems like a fail, but on the last one when it failed it was 0 ohms.

So now I am wondering, do you think the new one died quickly because it was a bad motor, or is there some other issue causing it? Should I replace the control board?

The motor I bought: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0718Z3T6Y/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Be anither fault somewhere, but this is not Home Imporovement...

Comment: The tags "appliances" and "dryer" were available so I thought it fit. And the description of the home improvement section says "The core of this site is around parts of your home that are typically included when you buy or sell it, the structure, utilities, and major appliances."

Comment: But not repairing them which needs elec & mech eng knowledge. The tags refer to mounting them... But we both will soon see - if your question gets close votes.

Comment: Would put money on another fault somewhere.  Motors usually way down on list to fail early, but could have got bad one.

Comment: @crip659 would you suggest I replace the control module?  I have tested everything else.

Comment: Find replacing to find a problem, usually not the best.  If control module can be replaced cheaply compared to having someone come and test, go for it.  Try also googling problems with that dryer model, bet someone had same problem, and cheaper than replacing parts.

Comment: OK good idea I will see if there is someone who can test it.  If I can't find someone would you replace motor (again) and control board?  I'm not 100% sure the old diagnostic applies to the new motor but I don't want to risk burning out the control board with the motor.  Though it is isolated with a relay so seems like a small risk.

Comment: @jsotola when you hit the start button it would blink as if it were operating but there would be nothing happening (no blower, heat, or spin).  I tested everything except the main board two days ago and the motor failed the test.  I replaced that and it worked for one day.

Comment: @jsotola I don't think so because there was 0ohms of resistance across the contacts on the motor meaning it was shorted out, the spec I had says it should have been 3.5.

I don't know what that means physically for the motor beyond that.

Comment: are you able to see the motor windings? ... if you can see them, do they look burned?

Comment: looking at the service manual ... if you apply power between the motor pins 4 and 5, then the motor should start up and run

Comment: did you operate the centrifugal switch when you measured the winding resistance? ... when the motor is stopped, the windings are connected in parallel, which would produce the 1.8 ohm reading ... 1.8 and 1.9 are the same reading

Comment: @jsotola no the windings look fine.  I tried to actuate the switch but can't seem to figure it out so you are right that it may not be a difference.

Should I try to apply power to the motor?

In another thread someone said that aftermarket motors don't work for Dryers.  Is that true?  This one isn't OEM.

Comment: Motors should work on almost anything, unless someone is using DRM which I doubt.  Motors are at basic just thing that rotates when you apply power to it.  Most differences are size and means of mounting.

Comment: OK I thought so.  My plan is now to find someone who can test the main board and if I can't I will just replace it and the motor (again lol).  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Is there a starting capacitor ? Many motors have a starting cap when this cap goes bad the motor can’t always start up especially under a load. Caps may be intermittent at first and yes motors that have centrifugal start run switches can use starting caps.

Comment: There is no capacitor on the motor that I can see.

Comment: Check that the drum is rotating properly. You could have a bad bearing or the felt seal has become worn or sticky.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120898/discussion-on-question-by-headsmartphone-i-replaced-the-motor-in-my-dryer-and-it).